# How can I add selective rows in a Mysql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I have a table with items (A,B) and periods. I would like to add rows that contain the missing periods per item (for item A add rows with periods 1 to 4, and for item B add a row with the period 3). If possible in a procedure or without actually changing the original table (in reality I have more than a 1000 items)

Original:

```
item period
a    0
a    5
a    3
b    2
b    4
```

Desired:

```
item period
a    0
a    1
a    2
a    3
a    4
a    5
b    2
b    3
b    4
```

Thank you

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: mysql version is 5.7.17

Comment: How many periods can there be?

Comment: I have maximum 240

Comment: So an item `a` could have any value of `period` from 0 to 240?

Comment: yep, and ideally i would like to add the missing periods in between the minimum and the maximum period for each item. Thank you for everything in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a numbers table.  Let me assume you have one:

```
select i.item, n.n as period
from (select item, min(period) as minp, max(period) as maxp
      from items
      group by item
     ) i join
     numbers n
     on n.n between i.minp and i.maxp;
```

If you don't have such a table, you can generate one:

```
select i.item, n.n as period
from (select item, min(period) as minp, max(period) as maxp
      from items
      group by item
     ) i join
     (select (@rn := @rn + 1) as n
      from items i cross join
           (select @rn := -1) params
      limit 241
     ) n
     on n.n between i.minp and i.maxp;
```